# Android's TextView with marquee in a ListView won't animate for the fist time it is shown

Tags: android, listview, marquee

I've got a ListView with a custom adapter. Every item in it contains a TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chat_name"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

I need this TextView to not be focusable, because I rely on the `onListItemClick()` method. As I learned, `onListItemClick()` won't fire if you set `focusable="true"`.

In the adapter I set:

```
TextView chatName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.chat_name);
chatName.setText(chat.getChatName());
chatName.setSelected(true);
```

And it works every time but first one. When an item is added to the adapter it shows on the listview, but it isn't marqueed. When item is clicked, another activity is displayed. After the user returns to the ListView, the item is suddenly marqueed. I want it marqueed all the time.

I have already tried subclassing the TextView with a method that overwrites `isFocused()` to always return true, but that didn't help. Behavior remained the same. I also experimented with various values of `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` attributes, but with no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use requestFocus() function as follows.

```
chatName.setSelected(true);
chatName.requestFocus();
```

I will work.

Answer (score 4):

In your custom adapter, add this into getView:

```
chatName.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, ....) 
    {
        chatName.setSelected(true);
    }
});
```